# A Sonar Snapshot dated in the future prevents new Sonar Analysis

Tags: sonarqube

Our maven project was build by Jenkins and sent for Sonar analysis dated 31 december 2014 (so in the future. I suspect someone changed the date of the server running Jenkins and Sonar ...)

In Sonar, the last snapshot is dated December 31, 2014 and this snapshot can not be deleted.

No more Sonar Analysis can be done :
[ERROR] 'sonar.projectDate' property cannot be older than the date of the last known quality snapshot on this project. Value: '2014-08-04T11:27:23-0500'. Latest quality snapshot: '2014-12-31'. This property may only be used to rebuild the past in a chronological order.

How to go back to a stable situation ? is it possible to delete data in the sonar database without corrupting datas : which queries to execute ? 
Or THE solution is to delete the project in Sonar and restart from scratch ?
Is there a way to rename the sonar project (for history purpose) and to start from scratch ?

Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

It is unfortunately not possible to delete the latest snapshot, and we strongly advise to not update the DB manually as it can have many side effects.

You can indeed change the project key (in "Configuration > Update key")) to keep its history for a while (but the name will remain the same) and restart a new analysis from scratch.